# Replace / Update Files in Mac OS X App Bundle

Tags: macos, deployment, bundle

when deploying software on Windows, it is relatively easy to update files in a program folder by running a setup program (e.g. generated with NSIS) with admin rights. Is there an analogous way on Mac? Is it possible to exchange files in an installed app bundle and how is it done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If it's an app distributed via the App Store or signed (or both), you can ***not*** replace files within an application bundle without breaking it (where it won't launch on subsequent attempts).

You didn't provide enough information in your question to explain what you are trying to do.  Is this for an application you are *writing* or is this for applications with site licenses or apps you don't control at all?

If this is for an application you are writing, Apple recommends installing resources in `~/Library/Application Support/` or `~/Library/Cache/` or other directories, and then -- in most cases -- you'd have to create some mechanism within your app to fetch and save updated resources.  There may be some stuff that the MacOS provides, like [`NSCache`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am new to Mac and I want to deploy my own Java based software in an adapted form for Mac OS X. The software is not distibuted via App Store and it is not signed. I am using JarBundler to create the App Bundle (+ some manual adaptation of the plist file) and create a dmg for deployment on CD. User data is stored in user.home, but the rest is included in the app bundle. An app bundle just seems to be a directory structure. I wondered if it is possible to replace files within this structure automatically. Otherwise, the user would have to copy a file manually.

Comment: I still think it would be smarter to use the folder hierarchy provided in '~/Library/Application Support` or `~/Library/Cache/` or `~/Library/Preferences`, especially if Apple decides to lock down *all* apps and application packages on future versions of MacOS.

Comment: It seems to pretty easy: As long as you have admin privilegies, unsigned app bundles can easily be written, even when they reside in the program folder. I use a separate process to replace the according contents. Seems to work fine!